# How to create a custom new form for a Document Library (to add it in a SP Solution)?

Tags: 2010, document-library, custom-list, custom, newform

I needed to create custom forms for a SharePoint `list` and I found these articles
([1](https://ikarstein.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/walkthrough-create-custom-sharepoint-2010-list-form-for-deployment-in-a-visual-studio-2010-project/) and [2](https://ikarstein.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/walkthrough-create-custom-sharepoint-2010-list-form-for-deployment-in-a-visual-studio-2010-project-part-2/)) that gives really good explanations to do it step by step.

Now I want to do the same for Document Library.

Comment: There are no NewForms for document libraries, only Edit and display forms.

Comment: @EricAlexander ... and upload.aspx

Comment: So the Upload.aspx replace the NewForm.aspx for the document library. All right ! Thank you. But even knowing that does not tell me how to add a new item in document library using a custom form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many guides out there that will walk you through creating custom forms as part of your custom solution.

The basic steps are:

1. Take a copy of the default new/edit/display form
2. Customise the form to your liking
3. Point to the form from your list/library schema

Here are two guides I used when I was first learning this stuff:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223431/Custom-SharePoint-List-Forms

http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2013/11/sharepoint-create-custom-list-forms-with-visual-studio-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

**Add fields:**

- Go to library ribbon
- Library settings
- At the "Columns" Section you can add columns the same way you add it to a list or content type

**Customize:**

You can add webparts to forms the same way you can add them to normal pages.

- Go to Library Ribbon
- Select Form Webpart => Default Edit Form
- Than you can use a content webpart to customize the form with Javascript (Add Webpart Link)

A great way to customize the form is this:
http://www.markrackley.net/2013/08/29/easy-custom-layouts-for-default-sharepoint-forms/

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm looking for something much more like [this](https://ikarstein.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/walkthrough-create-custom-sharepoint-2010-list-form-for-deployment-in-a-visual-studio-2010-project/). Even if the solution you provided is working, it is not usable for a solution intended to be deployed in a production environment.

Comment: As I said: This is best practice.We use this in scenarios with 5 digit amounts of users (including deployment over three levels)

Comment: More reasons not to use folders/separate libraries:
http://sharepointmaven.com/12-reasons-folders-sharepoint-bad-idea/

Comment: I can't see how this is helping me out. I want a step by step walkthrough showing how to add the custom form to a solution package. I don't want to have to make the procedure everytime I have to deploy the solution on customers servers. It's like creating a list using the sharepoint UI directly on the web site...this is not relevant, sorry. Or may be I'm missing something ?